# Spyder: Edit template.py file (Need variable for the current filename)

Tags: spyder

Yo, guys.

I would like to edit the template.py file in Spyder editor.

template.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
@File    :   -
@Date    :   %(date)s
@Author  :   Jane Daw 
@Contact :   ****@gmail.com
"""
```

How could I retrieve the current file name ?
What is the Spyder varible that describes it ?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I think that's not exposed in our template, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is no such variable. Here is [a bug report](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2884) that asks similar things since 2015-12-27. [This issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/17017) also suggests only `date` and `username` are suported.